# Plotting horizontal lines in a for loop with pandas data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am a beginner in python and I am trying to plot horizontal lines of yearly averages of a pandas time series with shape of (12,), indicating the 12 years. I have tried this:

```
plt.figure()
j=0
for i in range(0,np.shape(df_year)[0]):
    plt.axhline(periodData_yearAvg[i],xmin=j,xmax=j+1)
    print j
    print periodData_yearAvg[i]
    j=j+1
```

However, what I get is a horizontal line from 0 to 1 with only the first element of the pandas series.

I know that for example in MATLAB we have "hold on" command which plots the new value in the same plot. Is there a same option in Python?

Comment: You should always provide a [mcve] of the issue. Looking at the code you should indeed get as many lines as you have rows in `df_year`, but since we do not have a [mcve], we cannot help you.

Comment: Quoting from the doc string _"xmin : scalar, optional, default: 0
    Should be between 0 and 1, 0 being the far left of the plot, 1 the
    far right of the plot." otoh you use intervals outside of the plot area for all horizontal lines except the first one... try `xmin=j/12, xmax=(j+1/12)`

Comment: Thank you for your post. Now I am having a different graph, but still not what I was looking for. I am using explorer and I can't see the option for attaching a figure. But I explain the figure: now the x axis is still between 0 and 1, and I have 12 horizontal lines between 0 and 1, on their specified y values.

Comment: You cannot attach figures to your post until you have enough points... I didn't read your comment because I was working on a complete answer, that hopefully (the last part in particular) answers your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment, you seemingly misunterstood the semantics of `xmin`, `xmax` that should be fractions `0≤x≤1` of the x-axis.

The correct way to use them, in your particular use case, is

```
In [42]: N, n = 12, 12.0  # an integer and a float, so it works also in Python 2
In [43]: data = np.random.randint(50, 80, N)
In [44]: for j in range(N):
    ...:     k = j+1
    ...:     plt.axhline(data[j], xmin=j/n, xmax=k/n)
```

To have a better appearance you can finish with

```
In [45]: plt.xlim((2016-N,2016));
In [46]: plt.xticks(np.linspace(2016-N, 2016, N+1));
In [47]: plt.grid();  # of course gridding is optional
In [48]:
```

to obtain
[image]

Comment: Dear gboffi, thank you again for your explanation. I copy paste your code and still the same graph with only one horizontal line from 2004 till 2016 with a value between 60 to 65. I think there is an issue with my plotpy using ssh.

Comment: Which is the version of Python that you use? in Python3 `3/12 == 0.25` because division always give you floating point numbers, but in Python2 `3/12 == 0` because it is interpreted as integer division. ፨ I am a fool... it is apparent from your `print` statements that you use Python2! Please use `plt.axhline(data[j], xmin=j/12.0. xmax=k/12.0)` and every bit will find its place... (no `12` that is an integer literal but `12.0` that is a float literal). I'm sorry for my misunderstanding.  Thank you for approving the answer on an act of faith!

Comment: Yes Yes, Thank you so much. It is now the same as you put it here.